Customizing Error Responses for Non-Existent Resource IDs in API Platform
I'm using API Platform in my Symfony application and encountering an issue with the automatic Get() route when searching for a resource that doesn't exist. Currently, API Platform returns a default error response like this:
{
    "@id": "/api/errors/404",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "detail": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "type": "/errors/404",
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\repas_siege_api\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\State\\Provider\\ParameterProvider.php",
            "line": 99,
            "function": "provide",
            "class": "ApiPlatform\\State\\Provider\\ReadProvider",
            "type": "->"
        },
        // more trace details...
    ]
}

Instead, I'd like to customize this response to something like:
json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Id not found"
    }
}

Is there a way to modify or override the default error response format for Get() routes in API Platform when a resource with a specified ID is not found?
I've reviewed the documentation but haven't found a clear solution yet. Any guidance on how to achieve this customization would be greatly appreciated.
